# JS that increases select Field but no post result

Tags: javascript, php, html, select, post

I have an HTML form where I need multiple select boxes but with same name,
as the number of select fields is undefined. I used JavaScript to increment the select field by one when a button is clicked. But with same name as array like `forhead[]`. When I am submitting the form I'm unable to get selected values. I get simply nothing, not even the field name.

Here's the code:

```js
 function add_select(name){
  var id_name = name;
  var div = document.getElementById(name);
  var more= '<select name="'+id_name+'[]" class="form-control"><option value="0">NONE</option><option value="7">plugin one</option><option value="8">plugin two</option><option value="9">plugin three</option></select>';

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + more;
 }
```

```html
<a  onclick="add_select('forhead')"><div class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-plus">plus</span> </div></a>

<form method="POST" action="create_page.php">
    <div id="forhead">
      <select name="forhead[]" class="form-control">                
         <option value="0">NONE</option>
         <option value="7">plugin one</option>
        <option value="8">plugin two</option>
        <option value="9">plugin three</option>
      </select>


 </div>
  <input type="submit" name='save_page' value ="Save Page" class=" btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
</form>
```

Everything else is working file, but I'm not getting result in post.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add create_page.php file content to your question

Comment: its simply print_r

<pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>

Comment: when i do  var_dump($_POST['forhead']) i get - Undefined index: forhead

Comment: how about `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: Nothing for forhead. m getting other fields of form

Comment: your code works fine for me. http://bobloper.com/sandbox/so/select.php

Comment: can you verify that the `forhead` appears in the request from the browser?

Comment: if i dont add another select using that plus button. m getting the result. but when two pr more boxes used. this field just disappears.

Comment: no not getting in REQUEST @BizzyBob

Comment: seems like you must have more code.  maybe some other Javascirpt that is changing the POST...

Comment: normal bootstrap jscript included on page

Comment: So when you go to the 'Network' tab in the browser, the 'Form Data' shows all the fields except the selects?

Comment: I can only think of two explanations: 1) some JS is changing the form data when the post happens 2) you are overwriting the `$_POST['forhead']` value in your PHP in your create_page.php file.

Comment: unable to find any 'Form Data' Inside network tab :(

Comment: Updated: https://snag.gy/FaQB6v.jpg

Comment: i checked... other form data are thr but not the select fields